# Regular expression with \\p{Ll}

Tags: java, regex

I am validating password. It can contain:

- `[a-z]`
- `[0-9]`
- `[#@]`

With:

- Minimum Length of `8`
- Maximum Length of `14`
- Must contain at least one small character, number, # or @ (but no upper case letter)

Here is my code:

```
String regExp="^(?=.\\p{Ll})(?=.*[#@])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,14}$";
String data="1aaaaA61@11";     ## password user enters ##

System.out.println(data.matches(regExp));
```

The result is `true`

Comment: You should not put a maximum length on passwords or restrict the characters that can be used. Both will weaken passwords. 14 characters should be a *minimum* in today's age. If that's out of your control, hopefully you can pass that along to whomever set those password rules.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using this regex:

```
^(?=.*\\p{Ll})(?=.*[#@])(?=.*\\d)[\\p{Ll}\\d#@]{8,14}$
```

`[\\p{Ll}\\d#@]{8,14}` will not allow uppercase letter in your input, it allows 8 to 14 length of following characters:

- lowercase letter
- digit
- `#` or `@`